# Responsive design with flex and media queries

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

I'm trying to get my elements  on the same line until 992px ( windows) but they don't.

[image]

I have to reproduce a mockup and I'm afraid to abuse of media queries by reducing they size (someone is going to check my work) and I don't know if it's relevant to use many media queries or less possible :

```css
.section-2
{
 display: flex;
 margin-top: 25px;
}



.card_hostings{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    width:50%; 
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    gap: 20px;
    left:26px;
}

#hosting{
    width: 100% ;
}

#show_more{
    width: 100%;
}

.item{
    width:235px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10%;
    border-top-left-radius:10% ;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 4px 4px 15px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.item img{
    width: 100%;
    height:110px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10%;
    border-top-left-radius:10% ;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    
}
.item p {
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.card_hostings--title{
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.card_hostings--title + p {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color:gray;
    
}

.notes_stars {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color:#0065FC;
    font-size: 14px;
}




.card_hostings--2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: lightgray;
    align-items: center;
    width:auto;
    margin-left:70px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    gap:15px;
    
}

.card_hostings--2 > h1
{
position: relative;
left:-50px;
margin-top: 20px;
bottom: 15px;
}

.card_hostings--2 .fa-chart-line {
position: relative;
left:120px;
margin-right:20px;
}


.item--2{
    width:100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
    padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.item--2 img{
    width:40%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height:150px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius:15px;
    float: left;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}

.card_hostings--title2{
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.card_hostings--title2 + p {
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: gray;
}

.notes_stars2{
    margin-left: 180px;
    color:#0065FC;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-2">
  <div class="card_hostings">

    <h1 id="hosting">Hébergements à Marseille</h1>

    <!-- FIRST CARD -->
    <div class="item">

      <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/auberge_cannebière.jpg" alt="Auberge La Cannebière">
      <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Auberge La Cannebière</h3>
      <p>Nuit à partir de <strong>25€</strong></p>
      <div class="notes_stars">

        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star" style="color:#F0F0F0"></i>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SECOND CARD -->
    <div class="item">

      <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_du_port.jpg" alt="Hôtel du port">
      <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Hôtel du port</h3>
      <p>Nuit à partir de 52<strong>€</strong></p>
      <div class="notes_stars">

        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- THIRD CARD -->
    <div class="item">

      <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_Les_mouttes.jpg" alt="Hôtel Les mouettes">
      <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Hôtel Les mouettes</h3>
      <p>Nuit à partir de 76<strong>€</strong></p>
      <div class="notes_stars">

        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star" style="color:#F0F0F0"></i>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- FOURTH CARD -->
    <div class="item">

      <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_de_la_mer.jpg" alt="Hôtel de la mer">
      <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Hôtel de la mer</h3>
      <p>Nuit à partir de 46<strong>€</strong></p>
      <div class="notes_stars">

        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star" style="color:#F0F0F0"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star" style="color:#F0F0F0"></i>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- FIFTH CARD -->
    <div class="item">

      <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Auberge_Le_Panier.jpg" alt="">
      <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Auberge Le Panier</h3>
      <p>Nuit à partir de <strong>23€</strong></p>
      <div class="notes_stars">

        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star" style="color:#F0F0F0"></i>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- SIX CARD -->
    <div class="item">

      <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_chez_Amina.jpg" alt="">
      <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Hôtel chez Amina</h3>
      <p>Nuit à partir de 96<strong>€</strong></p>
      <div class="notes_stars">

        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>

      </div>

    </div>

    <p id="show_more">Afficher plus</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card_hostings--2">
    <h1>Les plus populaires<i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i></h1>

    <div class="item--2">

      <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_Le_soleil_du_matin.jpg" alt="Hôtel Le soleil du matin">
      <h3 class="card_hostings--title2">Hôtel Le soleil du <br> matin </h3>
      <p>Nuit à partir de 128<strong>€</strong></p>
      <div class="notes_stars2">

        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="item--2">

      <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Au_coeur_de_l'eau_Chambres_d'hôtes.jpg" alt="Au coeur de l'eau Chambres d'hôtes">
      <h3 class="card_hostings--title2">Au coeur de l'eau <br> Chambres d'hôtes</h3>
      <p>Nuit à partir de 71<strong>€</strong></p>
      <div class="notes_stars2">

        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star" style="color:#F0F0F0"></i>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="item--2">

      <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_tout_bleu_tout_blanc.jpg" alt="">
      <h3 class="card_hostings--title2">Hôtel Tout bleu et <br> Blanc</h3>
      <p>Nuit à partir de 68<strong>€</strong></p>
      <div class="notes_stars2">

        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star" style="color:#F0F0F0"></i>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Should I recode it or use many media queries ?
Thanks for reading

Comment: post as much code as is needed to reproduce the issue. Leaving out vital parts that make it not reproducable is worse then psoting a little mroe then necessary. See the good thing: Cutting down the code to be minimal reproducable is the first step of debugging yourself. After that you have a smaller frame of the code fragments that cause the issue.

Comment: Sorry but my understanding of english is not fluent so can you rephrase please ? I'll do whatever it needed .